# OpenSSL AES_CBC-256 decrypting without original text length in C++

Tags: c++, security, encryption, openssl, aes

I have this code that I found on SO and it works. My problem is that encryption and decryption are in the same file. Naturally, I want to separate them into two functions. The problem is the decoder needs the original input length. Isn't it a security vulnerability? How can I decrpyt without knowing the original length of the input?

```
/* computes the ciphertext from plaintext and key using AES256-CBC algorithm */
string cipher_AES(string key, string message)
{
    size_t inputslength = message.length();
    unsigned char aes_input[inputslength];
    unsigned char aes_key[AES_KEYLENGTH];
    memset(aes_input, 0, inputslength/8);
    memset(aes_key, 0, AES_KEYLENGTH/8);
    strcpy((char*) aes_input, message.c_str());
    strcpy((char*) aes_key, key.c_str());

    /* init vector */
    unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    // buffers for encryption and decryption
    const size_t encslength = ((inputslength + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    unsigned char enc_out[encslength];
    unsigned char dec_out[inputslength];
    memset(enc_out, 0, sizeof(enc_out));
    memset(dec_out, 0, sizeof(dec_out));

    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, AES_KEYLENGTH, &enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, inputslength, &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);

    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key, AES_KEYLENGTH, &dec_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_out, dec_out, encslength, &dec_key, iv, AES_DECRYPT);

    stringstream ss;
    for(int i = 0; i < encslength; i++)
    {
        ss << enc_out[i];
    }
    return ss.str(););
}
```

Comment: You only need the original length if you want to validate the decryption produces the same number of bytes as were encrypted. The original length is simply the encrypted size minus any padding used to round up the size to an even multiple of the block size. The decryption will tell you how many bytes were actually decrypted

Comment: "I have this code that I found on SO and it works." Oh dear, that's not the right way to create a secure application. Cryptography is a bit weird in the sense that it can work 100% of the time, but still fail security-wise.

Comment: Hi, thanks but my question was not about security. It was about getting rid of the input length. If I were considering security, I would have asked: "I have this code that I found on SO, is it secure?". These are entirely different questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, AES encryption takes place 1-to-1 in blocks of 128 bits, so you already know the message size with a 16-byte accuracy by just looking at the ciphertext.

Then, for the last block you just need to determine where the message ends. The standard solution for that is to use padding (e.g. [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7)). Or just store the message length at the beginning and encrypt it together with the message.

You can of course continue using OpenSSL AES API, and [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31226760/485343) padding or some other mechanism yourself. But OpenSSL already has higher-level API (EVP), which does AES, CBC and PKCS padding automatically.

See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) official OpenSSL wiki page for an example of using the EVP API.

---

Unrelated notes:

- a fixed IV (especially zero IV) is insecure. Consider generating a random IV and storing it together with the ciphertext (e.g. using [RAND_bytes](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RAND_bytes.html)).
- check out also AES GCM mode for authenticated encryption (encryption + secure checksum), this way the encrypted message additionally becomes tamper-proof. See [this example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption).